# JSON-LD TypeScript classes

Tags: typescript, inheritance, schema.org

Several entities in my `NodeJS`/`TypeScript` project fit `Schema.org` definitions.

In example, a Rabbi entity is a kind of person. In order to expose a `JSON-LD` info in an `AMP` page, it would be easy if the entity could extend a predefined `Schema.org` Person class.

I found this nice package: https://github.com/google/schema-dts.

However, when i tried to use it like this:

```
// rabbi.ts file
import {Person} from "schema-dts/schema";
export default class Rabbi implements Person {
    ...
}
```

The following error showed up:

> A class can only implement an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members

Is there a way to auto-convert the type exposed in that package into classes?

Comment: `Rabbi` is not a `class` of `@Person`. It could be a `literal` for an `@Organization` with employee `@Role` with a `"name":"Rabbi"`. Obviously i'm using shorthand here to answer; the structure is larger and more defined.

Comment: Thanks @Jay Gray! Maybe i don't understand you. I meant that there are entities in my project that can be serialized to JSON-LD. Why a rabbi is not a person? There is a class for Rabbi anyway. i want it to be easier to serialize an instance of rabbi to a person JSON-LD.

Comment: please post the URI for the `Class` `Rabbi` - i'm not seeing it